# Question about evidence approximation when maximise wrt alpha (bishop chapter 3.5.2)

Tags: regression

I'm reading 3.5.2 of PRML book and am confused about the result of taking derivative of marginal likelihood function with regard to alpha. In particular regarding this function:

[image]

And according to the book the derivative with regard to alpha is:

[image]

So it seems m_N is not a function of alpha at all. But clearly it is a function of alpha according to this formula:

[image]

[image]

I must have missed something very obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: See this [answer.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395587/pattern-recognition-and-machine-learning-bishop-how-is-this-log-evidence-fun/404871#404871)
st 30 characters; you entered 16.

Comment: Great answer there, thanks a lot!